# XCodeBuild is not picking a configuration from my workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

This is my build command

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
           -scheme MySchemeName \
           -configuration AdHoc \
           clean archive
```

It works but its uses the default configuration for the archive scheme (which is `release`) instead of `AdHoc` which I specified.  In fact if you specify `-scheme ASchemeNameThatDosnNotExist` it still works and silently ignores the configuration name.

The project is setup like this:

```
xcodebuild -list
```

> ```
> Targets:
>     MyApp
>     MyAppTests
>
> Build Configurations:
>     Debug
>     AdHoc
>     Release
>
> If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.
>
> This project contains no schemes.
> ```

And the workspace like this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -list
```

> ```
> Schemes:
>     MyApp
>     Pods
>     Pods-AFNetworking
>     .. More pods
> ```

I.e. There are no targets and no configurations in the workspace.

How do I make a target visible to the workspace?  Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to configure target for workspace. You can create a scheme based on a particular target and then build a project passing scheme name. Setting configuration via '-configuration' switch works fine for me. I use xcode v. 5.0.2.

In general a configuration is set via action. You can create multiple schemes for archiving (with different configurations) and there's no need to pass configuration at all. Default configuration will be taken.

Comment: Yea I thought that might be the case.  I wanted to avoid multiple schemes since I actually have a few already.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: I guess You will not avoid having multiple schemes. Scheme is recommended in favor of target + configuration. Also tools such as xctool or apphance flow recommend (or even force) using schemes.

Comment: I am starting to agree with you now, but my biggest worry is that there would be almost duplicate schemes with just a different config on the archive action.  This would mean that one scheme might be updated for something, but the other would not, leading to bugs.

Comment: But I guess that could be advantageous too since you could add a build script in the post build action that decorates the icon with a build number for addHoc scheme but not for the app store scheme

Comment: But AFAIK schemes only differ with configuration. Other things (code) are common for all schemes. This is how apphance flow builds iOS apps exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Opal for your answer. I was initially mislead by your statement that '-configuration' was working. In fact, this does not work, and the specified configuration is silently ignored when performing an xcodebuild via the workspace:

```
xcodebuild -workspace $WORKSPACE.xcworkspace \
    -scheme $SCHEME \
    -configuration QA \
    clean archive -archivePath archives/$APP_NAME

xcodebuild -exportArchive \
    -archivePath archives/$APP_NAME.xcarchive \
    -exportPath . \
    -exportOptionsPlist $WORKSPACE/ExportOptions.plist

mv $APP_NAME.ipa $APP_NAME.$VERSION.$BUILD_NUMBER.ipa
```

However, after creating a custom shared scheme for that configuration, "myapp-QA", the build completes correctly:

```
xcodebuild -workspace $WORKSPACE.xcworkspace \
    -scheme $SCHEME-QA \
    clean archive -archivePath archives/$APP_NAME-QA

xcodebuild -exportArchive \
    -archivePath archives/$APP_NAME-QA.xcarchive \
    -exportPath . \
    -exportOptionsPlist $WORKSPACE/ExportOptions.plist

mv $APP_NAME-QA.ipa $APP_NAME.$VERSION.$BUILD_NUMBER.qa.ipa
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with using configuration & scheme arguments. A scheme has its own configuration and most probably it overrides configuration specified via `xcodebuild -configuration`.

You can solve it by using configuration & target:

```swift
xcodebuild -project <project>.xcodeproj \
           -configuration <configuration> \
           -target <target> \
           -sdk iphonesimulator \
           clean build
```